# Assign user role autometically based on country while user registration in woocommerse

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

```html
function wooc_extra_register_fields() {
  ?>

  <p class="form-row form-row-first">
  <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
  </p>

  <p class="form-row form-row-last">
  <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
  </p>

  <div class="clear"></div>

  <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
  <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>" />
  </p>

   <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
  <label for="reg_country"><?php _e( 'Country', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
<select name="country" >
  <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
  <option value="AU">Australia</option>
  <option value="IL">Israel</option>
  <option value="IT">Italy</option>
</select>
  </p>

  <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );

/**
 * Validate the extra register fields.
 *
 * @param  string $username          Current username.
 * @param  string $email             Current email.
 * @param  object $validation_errors WP_Error object.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wooc_validate_extra_register_fields( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
  if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
    $validation_errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
  }

  if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
    $validation_errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Last name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
  }


  if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
    $validation_errors->add( 'billing_phone_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Phone is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
  }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', 'wooc_validate_extra_register_fields', 10, 3 );
/**
 * Save the extra register fields.
 *
 * @param  int  $customer_id Current customer ID.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wooc_save_extra_register_fields( $customer_id ) {
  if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
    // WordPress default first name field.
    update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );

    // WooCommerce billing first name.
    update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
  }

  if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
    // WordPress default last name field.
    update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );

    // WooCommerce billing last name.
    update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
  }

  if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
    // WooCommerce billing phone
    update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );
  }

   if ( isset( $_POST['country'] ) ) {
    // WooCommerce billing phone
    update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'country', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['country'] ) );
  }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'wooc_save_extra_register_fields' );



if ($_POST['country']=='IT') {


$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
$user_data = array(
            'ID' => $current_user->ID,
            'role' => 'New Role Here' 
        );
wp_update_user( $user_data );  

   
}
```

I am developing plugin which will add extra field in my account page (User registration).
I will add first name, last name ,phone number and country.
But my main aim is to assign used role based on country like
if user has selected Italy then role should be Italy (I have already created this role in back end )

Could you please suggest me ,how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Write the code for adding user role inside woocommerce_created_customer hook.

```
function wooc_save_extra_register_fields($customer_id)
{

    if (isset($_POST['billing_first_name'])) {
        // WordPress default first name field.
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_first_name']));

        // WooCommerce billing first name.
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_first_name']));
    }

    if (isset($_POST['billing_last_name'])) {
        // WordPress default last name field.
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_last_name']));

        // WooCommerce billing last name.
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_last_name']));
    }

    if (isset($_POST['billing_phone'])) {
        // WooCommerce billing phone
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'billing_phone', sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_phone']));
    }

    if (isset($_POST['country'])) {
        // WooCommerce billing phone
        update_user_meta($customer_id, 'country', sanitize_text_field($_POST['country']));

        // Assign user role
        switch ($_POST['country']) {
            case 'IT':
                wp_update_user(array(
                    'ID' => $customer_id,
                    'role' => 'editor' // Update to desired role
                ));
                break;
        }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'wooc_save_extra_register_fields');
```